# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__asyncLoader') Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuetify.js

```
<template>
    <v-select
      v-model="selectedCustomerId"
      :items="customerOptions"
      item-text="name"
      item-value="id"
      label="Select Customer"
      outlined
    ></v-select>
  </template>
  
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { type Customers } from '../utils/types';
import apiService from '@/utils/apiService';
  
export default defineComponent({
    data() {
      return {
        customerOptions: [] as Customers[],
        selectedCustomerId: null as number | null,
      };
    },
    async mounted() {
      await this.fetchCustomerData();
    },
    methods: {
      async fetchCustomerData() {
        try {
            const response = await apiService.get<Customers[]>("API/URI");
            this.customerOptions = response;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching customer data:', error);
        }
      },
    },
  });
  </script>
```

Hi, im trying to create an dropdown using v-select with vuetify, but when i'm trying to populate the dropdown with the data i fetch from an api it throws in the console this message: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__asyncLoader')

I'm pretty new to vue 3 and vuetify.

EDIT: I think my problems is that this.customerOptions becomes a proxy object, and when i'm trying to use it in the v-select i get errors. What am im doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work when you remove the async and await keywords from the `mounted()`?

Comment: @MoritzRingler No, but in the v-select i can now see [object Object].. hmm i think it might be a problem that the object becomes a "Proxy" after the API call?

Comment: Do you have any answer? I met thi issue as well.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I chosed a regular select instead. Please let me know if you find a solution @JackChouMine

Answer (score 0):

You Must Be Use item-title For name And item-value For Your Object Id Like This code:

```
<template>
     <v-select
          :items="departmentOptions"
          item-title="name"
          item-value="id"
          @update:model-value="getItems"
          label="your Label"
          variant="solo"
          required
          reverse
          class="text-field"
   ></v-select>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
export default defineComponent({
  data: () => ({
   
    departmentOptions: [],
    selectedDepartmentId: "",
   
  }),
  methods: {
    getItems(item) {
       console.log(item);
      this.selectedDepartmentId = item;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("/Your Api")
      .then((response) => {
        this.departmentOptions = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      });
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- Error 1: due to entering the wrong key for item-title -->
    <v-select
      variant="outlined"
      :items="[{ id: 1, title: 'aaa' }]"
      item-title="name"
      item-value="id"
    ></v-select>
    <!-- Error 2: due to undefined item-title value -->
    <v-select
      variant="outlined"
      :items="[{ id: 1, title: undefined }]"
      item-title="title"
      item-value="id"
    ></v-select>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I was getting the same error using Vuetify on Nuxt 3. I got this error when closing v-selects:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__asyncLoader')
```

I worked out that this error was caused by erroneous key value used on the VNodes rendered by VSelect. VSelect uses the `item-title` for the key value, but my `items` had some entries without titles. I.e. `key` on the respective VNode would be blank or undefined. Ensuring every item had a title resolved the issue entirely.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!